# VSTS: Different merge commit message

Tags: git, merge, azure-devops, pull-request

I am not sure if this is because of `git` or `VSTS`: I get different messages when I complete a *pull request* from a branch into *master*.

If the source branch (*new-dev*) had only one commit (*new dev/1*) the merge commit message would be *Merged PR ##: < commit-message>* like *Merged PR 84: new dev/1*.

If the source branch (*dev*) had more than one commit (*dev/1*, *dev/2*, *dev/3*) the merge commit message would be *Merged PR ##: Merge < branch-name> to master* like *Merged PR 83: Merge dev to master*.

[image]
What's the difference for?

Answer (score 1):

`git` knows nothing of "pull requests", and the messages you're seeing are not standard git merge messages, so I'd say it's VSTS that's creating them.

Why the difference?  Presumably because (a) when it's just a one-commit merge they assume copying that commit's message gives the most detailed/useful description of what the merge does to the mainline, but (b) when there are multiple merges it isn't generally practical to include the details from *every* commit on the branch, so it gives a summary (merged such-and-such branch)

Comment: I can request a pull in git `git request-pull`. Is this similar to pull requests on vsts/github?

Comment: From the docs: "The request, printed to the standard output, begins with the branch description, summarizes the changes and indicates from where they can be pulled."  Now, I don't know if that's an old feature or a new one - I've never heard of it - but I stand by the statement that git knows nothing of "pull requests" (i.e. the activity defined by many git-hosting servers which could be initiated using the sort of information in this request)

Comment: Yeah. I've always thought of git not knowing of pull-requests, but then I saw that command. Now I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of vsts. This has nothing to do with git.

If there is only one commit, that commit (and therefore it's message) is the most specific description of the merge.

If there is more than one commit, the most specific description is the branch name. Therefore the difference.

In vsts when creating a PR you can name that PR any way you want. Then that name will be used in the merge commit message.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it to branch name?